# System.Exception: Internal error 20, found element in OpenXmlPowerTools.RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, power-tools-for-xml

I want to Accept all the track changes from word document. I have written following codes to do so.(I am using [PowerTools](https://powertools.codeplex.com) from codeplex.)

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
     OpenXmlPowerTools.RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions(wordDoc);
}
```

But above code is not working in some of the document. It shows System.Exception: Internal error 20, found element exception in some of the document.

So is there any issue with my word document? If yes then what should I look into document? In short I want to know that what is wrong with my document so that I can correct my document to run above code.

Another thing is that I am able to accept tracking changes in Word 2013/2010/2007 itself!!

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked same question on https://powertools.codeplex.com/discussions and they have updated  RevisionAccepter.cs file to get this resolved. 
[Thread from Power Tools Discussion](https://powertools.codeplex.com/discussions/641583)